# Make an image turn greyscale when the link is visited in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, href

I want an image that has a hyperlink to turn grayscale after the link is visited. Is this possible with HTML/CSS?

I tried first with the img tag, but it seems CSS can't control src or something like that. I'm now tinkering with div classes and the background-image property, but I can't seem to use :visited properly with it, and I'm not sure why. Actually, I have no idea what I'm doing. If anyone could provide a cool example of a code that'd be great!

```html
<a class="coolthing" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/eoem9Lk.jpg)" href="https://google.com/"></a>
```

```css
.coolthing {
height: 100px
width: 200px
background-size: contain;
}
.coolthing:visited {
filter:grayscale(1)
}
```

I've also tried:

```html
<div class="coolthing" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/eoem9Lk.jpg)"><a href="https://google.com/"></a></div>
```

```css
.coolthing {
height: 100px
width: 200px
background-size: contain;
}
.coolthing:visited {
filter:grayscale(1)
}
```

Comment: Go through this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/ and check the limitations. Also add semi-colon after the height, width and filter values.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to security issues.

Allowed styles are:

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and border-color for separate
  sides)
- outline color
- column-rule-color
- the color parts of fill and
  stroke

from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Comment: (UNTESTED) As a workaround to that you could use CSS to set a background colour (which will not be visible in the context of using a background image). Then use JS to check the background colour and apply a 'visited' class if the background colour is set. Then you can freely style your 'visited' class.

Comment: I've now tested the above, JS cannot reach into the 'visited' styles to it always gets back the CSS of the original element which means there's no trigger for this solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this maybe

```js
$('#link').click(function(){
    $("#image").addClass("coolthing-visited");
});
```

```css
.coolthing {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: contain;
}
.coolthing-visited {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link" class="coolthing" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img id="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work off the 'actual' visited link, only what has been clicked which means on load this won't work. Additionally as links are clicked from other tabs your current tab won't reflect this.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Well he didn't specify how the link should work...i just though it could be like common site use the link, with the target="_blank" and that works fine....i'll edit that...in jsfiddle works just fine...if i didnt understand what you mean, well, thats on me, my bad

Comment: Not to worry, my comment wasn't so much directed at you but at future readers who may find your answer and require a little more context for their situation.